# Transit visa for China with Philippines passport

Tags: transit, china, filipino-citizens

I hold a Philippines passport. I want to go from Hong Kong to the Philippines and back with the following itinerary. Do I need to apply for a transit visa? The website said to apply for a transit visa at the border. How does it actually work?

Both flights are on one ticket.

- MF382 Hong Kong International (HKG) to Xiamen Gaoqi International (XMN)
- MF827 Xiamen Gaoqi International (XMN) to Manila (MNL)

3 hours transit time.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a transit visa. You will, I assume, stay airside, which means you don't require a visa. You're flying with the same airline, Xiamen Air, so both flights will arrive at/depart from T3. You will not cross the border.

And anyway should you have to pass through Immigration and Customs, in case of a delayed flight or other emergency, the 24-hour Transit Without a Visa (TWOV) is available to you.